# How to compare two array of objects?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, compare

I have a class A:

```
class A {
   var identifier: String?
   var quantity: Int = 0
}
```

Two arrays of A instances:

```
var array1: [A] = [a1, a2, a3, a4]
var array2: [A] = [a5, a6, a7, a8]
```

I don't know which is the best way to check:
`array1==array2 if a1.identifier == a5.identifier, a2.identifier == a6.identifier, a3.identifier==a7.identifier, a4.identifier==a8.identifier` in Swift.

Please help me...

Comment: array1 and array2 will always be of the same size? show array count be a check also? or check should be on properties of each element in arrays?

Comment: @ddb: sorry, their counts are random

Comment: so if they have different counts, they should be classified as unequal, right?

Comment: What do you consider equal? If they have the same length? If they have the same items? Do the items all have to be at the same index?

Comment: @ddb: ya... I got it, but how about another case @-@

Comment: @Yannick: their contents are same, sorry for my poor English

Comment: so [a1, a2] == [a2, a1] should be true?

Comment: @Yannick: Yes, I think I don't care about order...

Comment: Why don't you mention that you don't count item order at all?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
let result = zip(array1, array2).enumerated().filter() {
    $1.0 == $1.1
}.map{$0.0}
```

Comment: @Rahul Tripathi, dear Rahul Tripathi can you please explain your code. It's interesting, but I can't understood.This is my code  let array1: [Int] = [1, 2, 3, 4]
        let array2: [Int] = [5, 6, 7, 8]
        
        let result = zip(array1, array2).enumerated().filter() {
            $1.0 == $1.1
            }.map{$0.0}
        print(result)

Comment: Event if this works, it looks like a copy paste code from somewhere without any explanation of the code!.@Rahul Tripathi

Comment: I do not think this is a good solution. It only works for one scenario i.e. when the two arrays are sorted in the same sequence.

Comment: It is an incorrect answer because [1,2,3] is equal to [1,2,3,4] with this comparison (zip chooses the length of the shortest array)

Answer (score 18):

**Swift 4**

The following method makes it much more easy.

**Method 1 - Using Equatable Protocol**

*Step1 - Make your class 'A' equatable as follows*

```
extension A: Equatable {
    static func ==(lhs: A, rhs: A) -> Bool {
        // Using "identifier" property for comparison
        return lhs.identifier == rhs.identifier
    }
}
```

*Step2 - Sort your arrays in ascending or descending order*

```
let lhsArray = array1.sorted(by: { $0.identifier < $1.identifier })
let rhsArray = array2.sorted(by: { $0.identifier < $1.identifier })
```

*Step3 - Use == or elementsEqual comparison*

```
let isEqual = lhsArray == rhsArray
```

**OR**

```
let isEqual = lhsArray.elementsEqual(rhsArray, by: { $0 == $1} )
```

**Method 2 (Without Equatable Protocol)**

*Step 1 - Sort Array as described in Method1, step 2*

*Step 2 - Use elementsEqual*

```
lhsArray.elementsEqual(rhsArray, by: { $0.identifier == $1.identifier })
```

Read more about [Array Comparison here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2949628)

Comment: elementsEqual is a great little function, never come across it before but it's exactly what I needed :)

Comment: Thank you for your response @Anand . But if I want to create new array with just equal objects for how can I do?

Comment: @ErkamKUCET you can use array.filter method.

Comment: @Anand Okay, Actually, my problem is that I have two arrays of the same type and I want to create a new array with the same ones from among these arrays.

Comment: @ErkamKUCET: You should go through [official doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array). There are many built in functions are available which you can make use of. If you still couldn't find the right method, ask it as a new question here.

Answer (score 9):

Assume your data like that:

```
struct Person
    {
        let name: String
        let id:  Int
    }

    var people1 = [
        Person(name: "Quang Hà", id: 42),
        Person(name: "Lý Hải", id: 23),
        Person(name: "Maria", id: 99)
    ]

    var people2 = [
        Person(name: "Maria yyy", id: 99),
        Person(name: "Billy", id: 42),
        Person(name: "David", id: 23)
    ]
```

This is the method to compare two arrays of people with id:

```
func areArrayPeopleEqual(people1:[Person], people2: [Person]) -> Bool {
    var array1 = people1
    var array2 = people2

    // Don't equal size => false
    if array1.count != array2.count {
        return false
    }

    // sort two arrays
    array1.sortInPlace() { $0.id > $1.id }
    array2.sortInPlace() {$0.id > $1.id }

    // get count of the matched items
    let result = zip(array1, array2).enumerate().filter() {
        $1.0.id == $1.1.id
        }.count

    if result == array1.count {
        return true
    }

    return false
}
```

Comment: There is no reason to use `.enumerate()` to get count of the matched items, but then filter will looks like `{ $0.0.id == $0.1.id }`

Answer (score 5):

This method could be used if you have some parameter to compare:

```
let difference = currentObjects
    .filter({ currentObject in
        !(newObjects
            .contains(where: { $0.identifier == currentObject.identifier }))
    })
```

Answer (score 4):

I found this really easy solution at https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/how-to-find-the-difference-between-two-arrays

```
extension Array where Element: Hashable {
func difference(from other: [Element]) -> [Element] {
    let thisSet = Set(self)
    let otherSet = Set(other)
    return Array(thisSet.symmetricDifference(otherSet))
 }
}

let names1 = ["a1", "A4", "a3", "a4"]//["John", "Paul", "Ringo"]
let names2 = ["a1", "a5", "a4","a1.1"]//["Ringo", "George"]
let difference = names1.difference(from: names2)
```

Answer (score 3):

First we extend `Equatable` class, to have a **DRY** code, than if the 2 arrays are always of the same size, or if at least the first one is <= than the second you can go with this solution.

*Pay attention that you are working with optionals, you may have to unwrap them before.*

```
class A {
    var identifier: String?
    var quantity: Int = 0

    init(identifier: String, quantity: Int) {
        self.identifier = identifier
        self.quantity = quantity
    }
}

let a1: A = A(identifier: "1", quantity: 1)
let a2: A = A(identifier: "2", quantity: 2)
let a3: A = A(identifier: "3", quantity: 3)
let a4: A = A(identifier: "4", quantity: 4)

let a5: A = A(identifier: "1", quantity: 1)
let a6: A = A(identifier: "2", quantity: 2)
let a7: A = A(identifier: "3", quantity: 3)
let a8: A = A(identifier: "4", quantity: 4)

var array1: [A] = [a1, a2, a3, a4]
var array2: [A] = [a5, a6, a7, a8]

func areEquals(array1: [A], array2: [A]) -> Bool {
    if array1.count < array2.count {
        return false
    }
    for i in 0...array2.count - 1 {
        if array1[i] != array2[i] {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}


extension A: Equatable {
    static func ==(lhs: A, rhs: A) -> Bool {
        //you can choose how and when they should be equals
        return lhs.identifier == rhs.identifier
    }
}
```

[image: Proof of working]

Answer (score 1):

try this code, let me know if it works

```
func toDictionary<E, K, V>(
    array:       [E],
    transformer: (element: E) -> (key: K, value: V)?)
    -> Dictionary<K, V>
{
    return array.reduce([:]) {
        (var dict, e) in
        if let (key, value) = transformer(element: e)
        {
            dict[key] = value
        }
        return dict
    }
}
```

then you can execute a check like below

```
let areEqual = array1.count == array2.count;
if areEqual {
    let dict1 = toDictionary(array1) { ($0.identifier, $0.quantity) }
    let dict2 = toDictionary(array2) { ($0.identifier, $0.quantity) }
    areEqual = NSDictionary(dictionary: dict1).isEqualToDictionary(dict2)
}
print(areEqual)
```

disclaimer: function `toDictionary` has been took form [here](https://ijoshsmith.com/2014/06/18/create-a-swift-dictionary-from-an-array/)