# How to compare elements of two arrays

Tags: arrays, swift

I want to compare the elements of two arrays and check if they are equal.
I already tried various solutions but nothing really works.

I tried the solution from 
[How to compare two array of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39161168/how-to-compare-two-array-of-objects)

This is my object:

```
struct AccountBalance: Decodable {
    let balance: Double
    let currency: String

    init(balance: Double, currency: String ) {
        self.currency = currency
        self.balance = balance
    }

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case currency = "Currency"
        case balance = "Balance"
    }
}
```

This is the code from the link I tried:

```
let result = zip(accountBalance, getsSaved).enumerate().filter() {
                $1.0 == $1.1
                }.map{$0.0}
```

But I get this error:

```
Closure tuple parameter '(offset: Int, element: (AccountBalance, AccountBalance))' does not support destructuring with implicit parameters
```

Comment: good question! I am still wondering how to sort the array first.

Comment: https://iswift.org/playground?FzNTP6&v=3

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`Array` provides a function `elementsEqual` which is able to compare two arrays without explicitly conforming to `Equatable`:

```
let result = accountBalance.elementsEqual(getsSaved) {
    $0.balance == $1.balance && $0.currency == $1.currency
}
```

**Edit:**

If you want to have the *equality* result **regardless of the order of objects in the array** then you can just add sort with each of the arrays.

```
let result = accountBalance.sorted { $0.balance < $1.balance }.elementsEqual(getsSaved.sorted { $0.balance < $1.balance }) {
    $0.balance == $1.balance && $0.currency == $1.currency
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, this only returns true if the arrays are sorted first

Answer (score 3):

I am guessing two arrays should be considered equal when they contain the **same elements, regardless of ordering**.

First, implement `Equatable` and `Hashable`.

I am using hashValue as an id so I can sort the arrays first.

Here is what your `AccountBalance` class should look like:

```
struct AccountBalance: Decodable, Equatable, Hashable {


   // Important parts!
    var hashValue: Int{
        return balance.hashValue ^ currency.hashValue &* 1677619
    }
    static func == (lhs: AccountBalance, rhs: AccountBalance)  -> Bool{
        return lhs.balance == rhs.balance && lhs.currency == rhs.currency
    }

}
```

Then create an algorithm that sorts the ararys and then check each elements by one by by if the contents are the same.

Here is the function that take use of `Equatable` and `Hashable`.

```
func isEqual(arr1: [AccountBalance], arr2: [AccountBalance]) -> Bool{

    if arr1.count != arr1.count{
        return false
    }

    let a = arr1.sorted(){
        $0.hashValue > $1.hashValue
    }

    let b = arr2.sorted(){
        $0.hashValue > $1.hashValue
    }

    let result = zip(a, b).enumerated().filter() {
        $1.0 == $1.1
        }.count

    if result == a.count{
        return true
    }

    return false
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I have one question: what exactly is this line doing: "return balance.hashValue ^ currency.hashValue &* 1677619"

Comment: You are giving a hashValue to the `struct`. It is used to sort the arrays first.

Answer (score 2):

I will suggest you implement the accepted answer of the link you provided because it controls that both arrays are the same size and it orders them.

But if you want that your code works I solved like this:

[image]

In order to have control of the comparison your struct should implement the Equatable protocol and overload the operator ==

```
extension AccountBalance : Equatable {}

func ==(lhs: AccountBalance, rhs: AccountBalance) -> Bool {
    return lhs.balance == rhs.balance && lhs.currency == rhs.currency
}
```

Then compare both arrays and check if contains false, if it does, one or more items in the array aren't the same.

```
let result = !zip(accountBalance, getsSaved).enumerated().map() {
    $1.0 == $1.1
}.contains(false)
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: Your answer is wrong. If two arrays are not sorted, the result is false.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about what the rest of your code does, but making the parameters explicit does make XCode happy:

```
let result = zip(accountBalance, getsSaved).enumerated().filter() { (arg) -> Bool in
    let (_, (balance1, balance2)) = arg     
    return balance1.balance == balance2.balance
}.map{ $0.0 }`
```

Tried `(_, (balance1, balance2)) -> Bool in` directly, but it wouldn't let me either

Answer (score 0):

Sample with several arrays:

```
import Foundation

let arr1: [String?] = ["word", nil, "word3", "word4"]
let arr2: [Double?] = [1.01, 1.02, nil, 1.04]
let arr3: [Int?] = [nil, 2, 3, 4]

var tuple1: [(title: String, number: String, coord: String)] = []

let countArray = arr1.count

for element in 0..<countArray {
    tuple1.append((arr1[element].map 
{String($0)} ?? "", arr2[element].map 
{String($0)} ?? "", arr3[element].map 
{String($0)} ?? ""))
}

print(tuple1)
```

result of printing:

```
[(title: "word1", number: "1.01", coord: ""), (title: "", number: "1.02", coord: "2"), (title: "word3", number: "", coord: "3"), (title: "word4", number: "1.04", coord: "4")]
```